# What motherboard can be used with a gen 3 AMD Ryzen without having to bios update it?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, build

I am building my first pc and I'm not very experienced. I don't want to update the bios since I do not own a gen 2 processor and it would be more comfortable just to build it and be ready to play, not taking it to some service so they can update it. I am going to build an AMD Ryznen 5 5600x with an rtx 3060ti. I find a good balance for my needs. What would be a good motherboard that supports 3rd gen straight out the box? I'm also trying to save up a little since these other parts are going to cost a lot, so a budget motherboard would. be great.

Answer (score 1):

In general:
Every motherboard using a B550 or X570 chipset should support the 3rd Gen Ryzen CPU's.
The B450 chipset boards don't.
The X470 only after a Bios update, if available. Not all vendors bother making an update for the X470 chipsets.

If you want to be absolutely sure you will have to check with the vendor of the motherboard.